# Metro modal flyout disables itself

Tags: xaml, mahapps.metro

I have used metro mahhapps flyout like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout  IsModal="True" IsOpen="True" Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200">
            <!-- Your custom content here -->
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Grid>
```

and it disables everything, even itself - I can not close it, nor can I close my application.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flyouts container must be located on `MetroWindow` level.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout  IsModal="True" IsOpen="True" Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200">
            <!-- Your custom content here -->
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```